# Can we create unstoappable alarm application in android

Tags: android, alarm

Currently i am working on Alarm type of application , in that program has to run the alarm continuously without any interfering from calls, other apps, mute button, home button.... etc
until the stop button clicked.

so please tell me ,is it possible we force fully play only alarm sound or beep when phone calls coming or any other sound playing (only come alarm sound ).